# R: Select every combination of 3 different codes from a column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a column in a data frame that I'm using for coding. I want to select three of these codes, but they must be different from one another, until all combinations are exhausted. Here is my "Code" column

```
Code
AA
AA
AA
BA
BA
BA
BA
CA
CA
CA
CA
AB
AB
AB
```

For example I would like groups that are

```
1 "AA" "BA" "CA"
2 "AA" "BA" "AB"
3 "BA" "CA" "AB"
```

But not

```
1 "AA" "AA" "CA"
2 "AA" "BA" "BA"
3 "CA" "CA" "AB"
```

I've tried writing a for loop that does random selection but it gets hung up because it's just that, completely random. Thus, it will select the same code twice.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shoudln't three nested for loops and a boolean do the trick? It would be mighty inefficient, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is called `codeDf`, you can do:

```
t(combn(unique(codeDf$Code), 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] AA   BA   CA  
[2,] AA   BA   AB  
[3,] AA   CA   AB  
[4,] BA   CA   AB
```

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks!